# CNN in Dlib Face Detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, conv-neural-network, face-detection, dlib

I want to understand how cnn works dlib face detected , as far as I know the cnn parameters and everything are in the mmod_human_face_detector.dat file, is there any way for me to read it?
Or is there any article about it for me to look into?

```
cnn_face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')
```

I searched github and dlib's articles but couldn't find it

Comment: https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quite clearly worded, but by the line of code you inserted I assume you are interested in a specific model rather than CNN in general.

The model listed by you is based on detecting objects with maximum margin, and you can find the article here: [MMOD](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.00046.pdf).